# Is the reason why this function parameter works is because of global scoping?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to understanding the syntax of JS and teaching myself. I'm not sure why the following "name" works when its invoked. I know that its being passed through to the text parameter but i guess i don't fully understand why that is. It appears to me that when the function is invoked its up to you to put in an argument and that is what makes the function reusable.

```
const name = "jane";

function toUpper(text) {
  const upperCased = text.toUpperCase();
  console.log(upperCased);
}

toUpper(name);

\\ JANE
```

Comment: In this case yes, In general it works also because you send name variable, which contains "jane" value.

Comment: Have you read the JavaScript Guide? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: The function takes a *parameter*, so you can call it with `toUpper("alice")` or `toUpper("bob")`. The variable `name` contains a string, so it's a valid argument for the function and calling `toUpper(name)` is the same as calling `toUpper("jane")` since `name = "jane"`. This is in no way reliant on global scope, it just *happens* to currently be there.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Thanks @VLAZ, got it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const name = "jane";
//    ^ is the name you've allotted for the string "jane"

function toUpper(text) {
  const upperCased = text.toUpperCase();
  console.log(upperCased);
}
// ^ defines a function that accepts a string and processes it


toUpper(name);
//      ^ is the equivalent of saying toUpper("jane")
```

```js
const name = "jane";

function toUpper() {
  const upperCased = name.toUpperCase();
//                   ^ variable defined outside of the function's scope
  console.log(upperCased);
//             ^ local variable defined to the scope of the function.
  
}

toUpper();

// upperCased will not be defined here because it is scoped to the function.
```